# SSJ - Non-thowable exception

Tags: javascript, exception, xpages

today I had a strange problem in my serverside javascript.

I have a scriptLibrary in which I have some error-handling (try {...} catch(e) {...})
But somethings wrong with the variable "e". On the command e.printStacktrace() (which works useally) I got an exception: **Error calling method 'printStackTrace()' on an object of type 'Error [JavaScript Object]'**

I have another library, in which I pass the exception to a Java Class which creates a log document in my database, using it thows another exception which says that the variable "e" is not a thowable Exception. Checking that with a print(typeof e) return only "object".

Shouldn't that be a kind of exception on which I can use the standard methods? Do you have any idea what could cause that?

Thanks in advance.

Matthias

Comment: If you want to pass it to a Java function you can use an Object as the parameter, instead of a Throwable. You can then test in that function what kind of Object it is and log it accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is not a Java Exception, this is why there is no stack information and no *printStackTrace()* method available.

Your code throws a Javascript error object. Try *e.getMessage()* or just a *print(e)* to get the reason for the failing of your code.

Comment: Thanks, that should work. But I was quite sure that e.printStackTrace was working in the past.